# Is it possible running docker on big endian, arm32, linux=2.6.34?

Tags: linux, arm, docker

I want to run docker on big endian, arm32, linux system. It seems it is impossible download directly. So can I compile docker from source to big endian?

Answer (score 1):

**No.** That's an ancient kernel. Docker needs at least 3.10 or so.
Seriously, though, why would you want to do something on a system that antique?

Comment: Thanks Marcus. If without the restriction of kernel version, it is work?

Comment: I don't know. Refer to the docker documentation yourself.

Comment: Also, you'll have to be very patient. This doesn't sound like a system where I'd like to do docker development on.